# Set difference in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query that gives me a `group_concat` of stores that a title is available in:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e52b53/1/0

The query I am currently using gives me this:

```
select 
    title.id, title.name, group_concat(distinct store order by store)
from
    version inner join title on version.title_id=title.id inner join version_price 
    on version_price.version_id=version.id 
group by 
    title_id

id  name    group_concat(distinct store order by store) 
1   Titanic Google,iTunes                               
2   Avatar  iTunes
```

I want to add an additional column that gives me the set difference between the following (hardcoded) stores: `("iTunes", "Google", "Amazon")`. The correct query would then give me:

```
id  name         group_concat(distinct store order by store)    not_on
1   Titanic      Google,iTunes                                  Amazon
2   Avatar       iTunes                                         Amazon,Google
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could join in a table with all stores. I will just list them in a subquery, but it would be better to actually create such a table:

```
select     title.id, 
           title.name, 
           group_concat(distinct store order by store),
           group_concat(distinct nullif(stores.name, store) order by stores.name)
from       version
inner join title 
        on version.title_id=title.id 
cross join (select 'iTunes' as name union
            select 'Google' union
            select 'Amazon') as stores
left join  version_price 
        on version_price.version_id=version.id
       and version_price.store = stores.name
group by   title.id
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d8f807/11)

Note that it is important to join `version_price` with an outer join now:

This is because an `inner join` would eliminate the non-matched values from the *stores* sub-query. With a `left join` that does not happen: instead, the fields of *version_price* are represented as `null` when for a certain *stores.name* there is no match in *version_price*.

So before the grouping happens, you have in fact more records, but these additional `null` values do not contribute to the first `group_concat`. They, and only those, do however contribute to the second one.

#### Improving the database model

It would be better design to have the stores listed in a reference table, indexed by name. Or even better, give those stores an `id` as well, and redesign your `version_price` table to use a `store_id` as foreign key, instead of `store` (name).

Comment: could you please explain why the `version_price` needs an OUTER JOIN now instead of INNER ?

Comment: Because an `inner join` would eliminate the non-matched values from the `stores` subquery. With an outer join that does not happen: instead the fields of `version_price` are represented as `null` when for a certain `stores.name` there is no match in `version_price`. So before the grouping happens you in fact have more records, but the `null` values do not contribute to the first `group_concat`. They, and only those, do however contribute to the second one.

Answer (score 1):

How about a subquery?

```
select title.id, title.name, group_concat(distinct v1.store order by v1.store), 
(select group_concat(distinct v3.store order by v3.store)
             from version_price v3 where v3.store not in 
             (select distinct v2.store from version_price v2                                                               
              where v2.version_id = v.id)
            )
from version v inner join title on title_id=title.id 
inner join version_price v1 on v1.version_id=v.id 
group by title_id
```

Fiddle version here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af9e98/7

Comment: It is possible to achieve this with single subquery http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84a42/1

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e52b53/45

As store names are hardcoded why not make something like that? At least it doesn't add additional joins into query execution plan.

```
select 
  title.id, 
  title.name, 
  group_concat(distinct store order by store) as ins,
  concat_ws(
    ',',
    if(group_concat(distinct store order by store) like '%Amazon%', NULL, 'Amazon'),
    if(group_concat(distinct store order by store) like '%Google%', NULL, 'Google'),
    if(group_concat(distinct store order by store) like '%iTunes%', NULL, 'iTunes')
  ) as not_on
from version 
inner join title on version.title_id=title.id 
inner join version_price on version_price.version_id=version.id 
group by title_id
```

Comment: R that's an interesting approach, thanks for the above. Could you please explain how the `concat_ws` statement works a bit more?

Comment: @David542 http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws

Comment: @David542 Oh. I guess you need to know how it works in this case. `concat_ws` does not concatenate `null` values and `if` statements returns `null` in case if store name is found in the `group_concat(distinct store order by store)` string. So as the result we get the string with stores that doesn't present in `group_concat(distinct store order by store)`. Quite dirty from the design point of view but as it doesn't make additional queries it could be faster than other implementation. Need additional tests on full DB of course.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation. What if there are 200 stores? Would you need to replicate that `if` statement 100 times? Or how would you construct that way with many store values?

Comment: There is possible solution with separated `stores` table and subquery - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cff4da/14